# Swagger Error while clicking on Execute

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am using Swagger editor locally and my yaml code is proper. I am getting the below error when I click on Execute button. I am also getting this error when I run it online.

Is there any other way to view the output?

Error Details: TypeError. Failed to Fetch[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIhF1.png)

Comment: 1) How do you run Swagger Editor (via docker / npm or by simply opening the index.html page in your browser)? 2) Which host the requests are sent to?

Comment: @Helen 1)by opening index.html (2) hosted on Azure

Comment: are you solving the problem ??